# SQL Query for results from 7 days ago

Tags: sql, oracle, equals

I have a SQL query that I need to update to pull results from exactly 7 days ago. At the moment the query is looking at result 7 days and before. I can't seem to find a character that changes the > to an equals.

```
SELECT
   distinct(cl.RIID_),
   cl.EMAIL_ADDRESS_  
FROM
   $A$ cl  
JOIN
   $C$ bro 
      ON cl.EMAIL_ADDRESS_ = bro.EMAIL_ADDRESS_   
JOIN
   $D$ cms 
      ON cms.SKU = bro.ITEM  
WHERE
   cl.EMAIL_DELIVERABILITY_STATUS_ = 'D'   
   AND cl.EMAIL_PERMISSION_STATUS_ = 'I'   
   AND (
      cms.CATEGORYNAME = 'Desktop Systems' 
      OR cms.CATEGORYNAME = 'Refurbished Laptops & Tablets' 
      or cms.CATEGORYNAME = 'Laptops & Notebooks' 
   ) 
   AND (
      trunc(bro.ACTIVITY_DATE)
   ) >= (
      Trunc(Cast(From_Tz(Cast(Sysdate As Timestamp ), 'US/Pacific') At Time Zone 'Australia/Sydney' As Date)) - 7
   )
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: And what is wrong with `=`?

Comment: I receive the below error message                                                                 Error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Comment: Since your error is bubbling up through some kind of Java library, the issue may be in the Java library somewhere.... post the full story.

Comment: What is the datatype of `bro.ACTIVITY_DATE`?

Comment: The equality operator in SQL is `=`, not `==`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot see how changing the `>=` to `=` would cause that problem.  I get this type of error when I leave the operator out of the comparison, `where a` rather than `where a = b`.

However, you should use `IN` for the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE cl.EMAIL_DELIVERABILITY_STATUS_ = 'D' AND
      cl.EMAIL_PERMISSION_STATUS_ = 'I' AND
      cms.CATEGORYNAME IN ('Desktop Systems', 'Refurbished Laptops & Tablets' , 'Laptops & Notebooks' ) AND
      trunc(bro.ACTIVITY_DATE) = Trunc(Cast(From_Tz(Cast(Sysdate As Timestamp ), 'US/Pacific') At Time Zone 'Australia/Sydney' As Date)) - 7
```

And, remove the parentheses from around `distinct`.  `select distinct` applies to all the columns being selected.  The parentheses only mislead you and others who read the query.